# Remove view from library project

Tags: android, github

I am making use of this library

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

The problem is there is a grey patch that displays the name of the image and i want to remove that grey patch since I am not displaying the name. I have written a mail to the creator but no response from his side. Please help.

Comment: download the library and alter as per your requirement!! make that view component invisible !! also create the Future enhancement request  issue for enabling disabling the display name !

Comment: Import this Project as external project instead of adding the dependency to the build gradle file. After that you can customize this library, like removing the TextView from this layout file https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/render_type_text.xml and from the class where this view is used (or just hide the TextView)

Comment: yup i have been adding it as a gradle dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally I managed to figure it out. Thanx to Ram also. I will just sum it up about how do we do it.

First download the zip file of the library extract it and open it in android studio and then follow each and every step from @Ram23 's answer. Thats it.

Now Open the project in which you have to import the PROJECT (which you just modified). Click on the project and go to NEW -> Module -> Import Existing Project -> Browse to the location of the project you modified and only import the **library module** we dont need the demo module and then finish it. Now compile the project to check that the library module is available. Now open the build.gradle file of the APP module and delete the gradle dependency of this project (**compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'**) if you have included it earlier if not then you are on the right track.

Now compile the project again you will get an error something like this

**Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer**

So now just open the build.gradle file of the library and delete this line

**apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'**

Now the last thing is open the build.gradle file of the APP module and add this line in your dependencies **compile project(':library')**

Thats all. Now just rebuild the project once again and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If U really don't want to display text over the image....

U can change few changes in the library .... and the project ....

Library:

inside library->res->layouts->render_type_text
remove "LinearLayout with TextView"
inside java->Animations-> delete DescriptionAnimation class
nearly 3-4 places in library DescriptionAnimation class reference is using .... U have to remove those lines ....

Project:

Inside the demo project U can't use ChildAnimationExample class

Inside the mainActivity remove .description(name) at textSliderView
U can't use case:action_custom_child_animation and  Case:action_restore_default -> remove 2nd line in the menu.

like this if U changed .... The text won't appear on image ....

Comment: Since we deleted the LinearLayout from the library project. The id for this (description_layout)  is not available. Should i delete those too.DO i ChildAnimationExample class from the demo module

Comment: Deleted the ChildAnimationExample class as it was not required not anywhere and i didnt understand this in your comment. (-> remove 2nd line in the menu.) Do you want me to remove the contents of the second item tag in the menu. And now I want to add this project as a library to my project . so should i import both the modules or only the demo module is fine. I am following this tutorial for adding a module as library. http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/

Comment: Simple .... dude.. inside the library remove 'description_layout' & DescriptionAnimation class...
after that don't use description_layout inside ur project...
In demo project few places description_layout r used ... so, remove over there ...

Comment: inside the library remove 'description_layout' & DescriptionAnimation class.
.If u r using inside ur project, After that as shown in the link add only  that 'library' folder to ur project.... take the reference of demo project to archive the  functionality

Comment: So finally I reached here. I opened that github project and followed your answer and then followed this link ( http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/ ) and imported the module LIBRARY to my project and I also deleted the gradle dependecy of the github project since we are importing it now. So now after importing it all the views and the classes used were not found so I added LIBRARY module as dependency. But still I get an error like this ( Error:(22, 47) error: package com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes does not exist ). Any suggestions

Comment: My suggestion is first open Android Image Slider complete project in studio ( what ever U downloaded from github ), what ever changes required ( My Answer ) do it in demo project, once sussed do it in ur's . After sussed create a **new project** File -> import model -> select folder upto 'library' in demo project. after that in 'app gradle'  add ** compile project(':library') **   .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88691/discussion-between-sagar-devanga-and-ram23).